# RewriteRule with P flag not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy

I put a RewriteRule in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.test\.ch$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.test.ch/plu/sub/%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&id=3 [P]
```

and when I try to acces to the url demo.test.ch, in my error log I have something like

> demo.test.ch/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/plu/sub/&id=3&id=3&id=3&id=3&id=3&id=3&id=3&id=3&id=3&id=3

until I have an error than the URL is too long...

My question is : Why my proxy copy to much time the url ??

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have `[NC]` on your `RewriteCond`? Neither of those flags makes sense there.

Comment: Yeah this is better without [NC] !!! Now I have only 2 times ! :D 
> demo.test.ch/plu/sub/plu/sub .. Is there a way to know why I have it two time ?

Comment: I just change my server, and having the same problem now.. :-( ... Some one know how to figure out ?

Thank you